# Swaping pointers, deleting second object and create new pointer to second

Tags: c++, pointers, swap

I'm trying to swap a pointer but all I get is access errors, are there any way to do this?

```
void Swap(someObject *first, someObject *next)
{
     delete first;
     first = next;
     // I'm guessing this delete first pointer as well ?
     delete next;
     next = new someObject();
};
```

**Clarification on the method:**
It should just swap first with second and create a new instance of "someObject" on second, it shouldn't swap like = FIRST = SECOND, SECOND = FIRST. Just first becomes second, and second becomes a new object or a new pointer to an object.

Second = Next.

**SOLUTION**

```
void Swap(someObject*& first, someObject*& next)
{
    std::swap(first, next);
    next = new someObject();
};
```

Comment: your solution leaks `first`, you are aware of that, aren't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this swap idiom instead.  Yours modifies the parameters (and deletes both objects) but does not actually swap the pointer values at the call site.

```
template <typename T>
void Swap(T & a, T & b)
{
    T x = a;

    a = b;
    b = x;
}
```

However, you could just as easily use `std::swap` for this; it will effectively do the same thing this template function does.

Comment: Thanks. This did exactly what I wanted, I just add next = new someObject() and first is the earlier "second" object.

Comment: Not the code, but std::swap did the same thing instead of using a method I could just use that.

Comment: Make sure you `delete next`, if you have ownership of the object pointed to by `next` and intend to discard it.

Comment: Later, next becomes first and so on... and when exiting program I'll delete it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is, but you are missing something. When you pass `someObject *first`, what happens is that in your function, there is a copy of the pointer that you passed, named `first`. Therefore if you change the value of `first`, you change the value of the local variable and it will not propagate to the original variable.

What you need to do is pass a reference to the pointer, in this way:

```
void Swap(someObject*& first, someObject*& second)
{
     delete first;    // Will delete whatever first points to
     first = second;
     delete second;   // first will now point to a deallocated object, you'd better set first = nullptr
     second = new someObject();    // Will really set second to something new
};
```

If you need just to swap two pointers, you can also use the standard library utility function `std::swap`.

I hope that helps.

Comment: After executing this function, the pointer referenced by `first` will point to a deallocated object (it will be a dangling pointer).  This is a bad scenario.

Comment: True, will add that to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Are the argument call the same, like Swap(&first, &second)? Because it doesn't work. Still get the same errors.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any access errors in that particular snippet, but you are indeed deleting both memory locations.

Note that outside your function, both pointers will be dangling because you're not modifying them, but copies.

To make the modifications persistent outside the functions, you'll need to pass the pointers by reference.

```
void Swap(someObject*& first, someObject*& second)
```

After calling this version, `second` will point to a valid location, `first` will not (because you delete the memory and never re-assigned the pointer).

Also, to swap, you can just use [`std::swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/). Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

This for sure will result in access error since you're, at best, swapping *local copies* of the pointers. The arguments passed in must be *references* to pointers:

```
void Swap(someObject*& first, someObject*& second)
{
   someObject* temp = first;
   first = second;
   second = temp;
};
```

And btw, do not change the meaning of a well known name like 'swap' to mean some arbitrary exchange involving delete and new. swap means what it means. If you want a fancy operation that does your fancy assignment/delete/new, name it something else.

> it should just swap first with second and create a new instance of
>   "someObject" on second,

This is no Swap no matter how you slice it. I would call it 'Shift', but lets just call it MyOperation:

```
void MyOperation(someObject*& first, someObject*& second)
{
   someObject* temp = new someObject;
   delete first;
   first = second;
   second = temp;
};
```

Note how temp is *preallocated* since is the most likely to throw and you want to leave things in a [coherent state in case of exception](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++.htm). The delete and the simple pointer assignments cannot throw.

Comment: *Pedantic* - "This for sure will result in access error" - not really. Only if you attempt to use the values afterwards.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, I agree it's awful, but the "for sure" implies the code is illegal, which it's not.

Comment: ... but if you never access them afterwards, why would you Swap them?

Comment: I agree swapping without using is pointless. My point still stands.

Comment: Correct, if you only look at the code in the post, you can make that claim. But there, is always some context assumed, eg. we all assumed that `first` and `second` were allocated using `new` to start with...

Comment: I would guess the OP intent is more like a 'Shift' method: original `first` is deleted, original `second` becomes returned `first` and returned `second` is a new object.

Comment: Yes, second becomes new object while first is second.